# Generated graphs are getting overlapped

Tags: python-2.7, matplotlib, graph

i tried the following code i am getting the perfect graph for for data_set1_decision only for others the graphs are getting overlapped i mean second graph is plotted aganist the first graph,but i want it in an new graph and save any help

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import csv as csv
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def visualize_the_data_sets_results(method,set,feature):
    x2 = np.linspace(0, 3.5,80)
    poly_deg2 = 3
    coefs2 = np.polyfit([1,2,3], method, poly_deg2)
    y_poly2 = np.polyval(coefs2, x2)

    plt.style.use('ggplot')
    plt.plot([1,2,3], method, "o")
    plt.plot(x2, y_poly2)
    plt.ylabel("prediction_accuracy")
    plt.xlabel("features")

    plt.show()

    if set == 1 and feature == 1:
        plt.savefig('C:\Users\mullapudi\Desktop\project\static\\data_set1_decision.png')

    if set == 1 and feature == 2:
        plt.savefig('C:\Users\mullapudi\Desktop\project\static\\data_set2_decision.png')

    if set == 1 and feature == 3:
        plt.savefig('C:\Users\mullapudi\Desktop\project\static\\data_set3_decision.png')

    if set == 1 and feature == 4:
        plt.savefig('C:\Users\mullapudi\Desktop\project\static\\data_set4_decision.png')

if __name__ == "__main__":
    data_set1_decision=[10,20,30]
    data_set2_decision=[40,50,60]
    data_set3_decision=[70,80,90]
    data_set4_decision=[25,50,75]

    visualize_the_data_sets_results(data_set1_decision,1,1)
    visualize_the_data_sets_results(data_set2_decision,1,2)
    visualize_the_data_sets_results(data_set3_decision,1,3)
    visualize_the_data_sets_results(data_set4_decision,1,4)
```

Comment: call `plt.figure()` at the top of your plotting function to force creation of a new figure.

Comment: I have added it as a formal answer below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to ensure that a new figure is created for successive plots, then you need to explicitly call the [`figure`](http://matplotlib.org/api/figure_api.html#matplotlib.figure.Figure) constructor at the beginning of your plotting function

```
fig = plt.figure()
```